# Rgui connects to Oracle DB, but RStudio fails

Tags: r, oracle, oracle10g, rodbc

I'm trying to connect to my Oracle DB through Rstudio but finding that it will only work through the basic Rgui. I am using R 32bit to match the DB architecture, which seems right as the basic Rgui is working properly. I will add screenshots below since I cannot create a reproducible example for this.

This is the error I get on Rstudio:

```
> ch <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=Oracle in OraClient10g;DBCName=*****;UID=*****;PWD=*****")
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver=Oracle in OraClient10g;DBCName=*****;UID=*****;PWD=*****") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state HY000, code 12560, message [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
2: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver=Oracle in OraClient10g;DBCName=*****;UID=*****;PWD=*****") :
  ODBC connection failed
```

But exactly the same code works on Rgui. It brings up a dialog box where I have to enter the "Service Name", if I enter the DBCName then the code works. (I've scrubbed out the service name, username and passwords in the screenshots, but the code used in Rstudio and Rgui is identical).

[image: what happens when I run odbcDriverConnect]

and it works

My session info is the following:

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RODBC_1.3-13
```